# Cannot create directory in tmp(overthewire bandit24)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mkdir, tmp, bandit

I'm trying to solve bandit24 on overthe wire on ubuntu virtual machine.
I have already seen the solution.
But i have a problem,when i try to create a directory on tmp as bandit24@bandit i get this message:

> Cannot create directory "name_of_directory": file exists.

If I try with find command there is only  the "." directory and with `ls` I get the message:

> Cannot open directory '.' : permission denied.

I also have tried with `ls -l` on tmp and I get the message:

> Cannot open directory 'tmp': Permission denied

What else could I do?
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to prepend `sudo` at your command. Seems you don't have permissions to read the /tmp directory, what is pretty weird.

Example that might works:

To list the /tmp contents:

```
sudo ls -l /tmp
```

To create the 'my_new_dir' inside /tmp:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/my_new_dir
```

Comment: The second option works, the new directory should be under the system provided directories (home/banditx/here or /temp/here)

Answer (score 0):

1. It means that there is a directory under /tmp/ with the same name that you specified. But since you did not create it (in this case, someone created with a different bandit user), you cannot view it. There is not read permission for bandit24 to access it.
2. Since /tmp/ is directory accessible for all user accounts, you cannot list the files/directories under it without the root permission. (Which means the root of the bandit machine has configured like that)

**What you need to do**
Try a random name. Create anything random under /tmp/. It will work.